# Exclude IStringLocalizer/GetString in Unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use IstringLocalizer in controller in asp.net core to read shared resources . 
In a method i have :

```
          foreach (var category in urlCategories)
        {
            if (category == _localizer.GetString("CategoryWebshop")) model.SelectedIndustries.Add(1);
            else if (category == _localizer.GetString("CategoryStore")) model.SelectedIndustries.Add(2);
            else if (category == _localizer.GetString("CategoryWebsite")) model.SelectedIndustries.Add(3);
            else if (category == _localizer.GetString("CategoryService")) model.SelectedIndustries.Add(4);
            else if (category == _localizer.GetString("CategoryProduction")) model.SelectedIndustries.Add(5);
            else if (category == _localizer.GetString("CategoryTrade")) model.SelectedIndustries.Add(6);
            else if (category == _localizer.GetString("CategoryRestaurant")) model.SelectedIndustries.Add(7);
            else if (category == _localizer.GetString("CategoryRealEstate")) model.SelectedIndustries.Add(8);
        }
```

In unit test GetString of localizer does not let the test to get 100%

[image]

How can i fix the problem or skip/exclude that part from testing ?
Thanks

Comment: Show how it is tested.

Comment: In the test file i mocked it :

            var localizerMock = new 
            Mock<IStringLocalizer<AnkiroController>>();
            const string key = "CategoryWebshop";
            const string value = "Webshop";
            var localizedString = new LocalizedString(key, value);
            localizerMock.Setup(l => l[key]).Returns(localizedString);

Comment: Don't put code in the comments. Update the question.

Comment: You should rather refactor your code. That if/else chain looks like code smell for me